# Scroll css background image

Tags: jquery

I am looking a  help to move my container bg to move according to the 'scrollTop' for this, i wrote this function, but not work. any one help me. i decided to move my backgronud image with smooth way as well.

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
var moveSize = $(window).scrollTop();
$('#container.takeover1').animate({ 
    backgroundPosition: "0px "+ parseInt(-moveSize)+'px',
    easing: 'swing'
    }, 3000 );

});
```

any one help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're just trying to keep the background static on the page when the window scrolls, why not just use `background-attachment: fixed` in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try using negative vertical postiion eg

`backgroundPosition: 0 -100px`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bg').scroll(function(){
var x = $(this).scrollTop();
$(this).css('background-position','0% '+parseInt(-x/10)+'px');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/Vbtts/1365/)